# Eclipse doesn't find ant-tasks

Tags: eclipse, ant

I am using a development environment that is eclipse-based (Tibco AMX Business Studio). The product specific eclipse extensions among other features also provide a couple of ant tasks that should allow to script certain processes. In the case at hand here I want to create and pack up the project into a product specific container (a so-called daa-file) for which there exists an ant-task "sds.createDAA".
That and other product specific ant-tasks are listed in the eclipse ant configuration (under Preferences => Ant => Runtime => Tasks). The entry shows the name of the task, the class implementing it and the .jar file containing the code and more.

Also, the eclipse ant editor obviously finds and recognizes these tasks, at least it provides tool help (Ctrl-blank) and task-specific bubble-help etc.

The corresponding ant-target reads as:

```
...
<target name="createApplicationDAA">
    <sds.createDAA 
        projectName="${csite_project_name}" 
        daaLoc="${deploymentArtifactsDir}/${csite_project_name}.daa" 
        includeApplicationReferences="true" 
        overwriteExistingDAA="true">
        <application compositeName="${csite_project_name}">
        </application>
    </sds.createDAA>
</target>
...
```

But when I try to run the build.xml-file containing the above snippet I get an error that this ant-task can not be found:

```
W:\LHAPI_FlightInfo_csite\build.xml:25: Problem: failed to create task or type sds.createDAA
```

How/where does eclipse's ant specify the classpath for all those tasks?
Why are tasks known during edit-time not found during execution time (all inside eclipse or business studio, resp.)?

Hope I could make myself clear...
M.

Answer (score 0):

It [looks like](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_bpm/1.3.1_july_2012/doc/html/Composite%20Development/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#context=Composite_Development&file=t_Running_the_Command-Line_Interface.htm) Tibco provide a command line wrapper for ant - amx_eclipse_ant - located at TIBCO_HOME/studio/3.5/eclipse.

I guess that tool sets up the classpath for the custom tasks.

If you can find that tool and execute it from the command line, you could also execute it as an "External Tool" from Eclipse -- if you can't find a place in the development environment that provides that tool already.